# criterion for direct product of H and G to be cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

Criterion for $G\oplus H$ to be cyclic.
Let G and H be finite cyclic groups. Then $G\oplus H$ is cyclic if and only if $\left | H \right |,\left | G \right |$ are rel. prime.

Proof:

Let $\left | G \right |=m$ and $\left | H \right |=n$ so that $\left | G\oplus H \right |=mn$.
To prove the first half of the theorem, assume $G\oplus H$ is cyclic.
Suppose that $gcd\left ( m,n \right )=d$ and $\left ( g,h \right )$ is a generator of $G\oplus H$.

Here is where I am unable to understand the theorem from which the author is making inference from (and if I may, very frustrating):

Since $\left ( g,h \right )^{\frac{mn}{d}}=\left ( e,e \right )$ ...

The fact that the author made this deduction implies that the order of $\left ( g,h \right )$ is $\frac{mn}{d}$.

I am unable to understand why the order is mn/d

I've tried looking back at the fundamental theorem of cyclic group, and the theorem for $\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle=\left \langle a^{gcd\left ( n,k \right )} \right \rangle$ for element $a$ in a group G and k of positive integer. 
But to no avail.
I'm weak in the whole gcd manipulation thingy and the author could be doing such manipulation.

Edit: I had posed this question a while back but received no satisfactory replies. As I'm reading through the book again to refine my understanding, I hope to understand this part of the proof.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking why $(g,h)^{mn/d}=(e,e)$, or are you asking why this implies the order of $(g,h)$ is $mn/d$?

Comment: Yes, I am asking why the order is mn/d.

Comment: That wasn't a yes/no question, but whatever. Any any rate, $(g,h)^k=(e,e)$ iff $g^k=e$ and $h^k=e$ iff $k$ is divisible by $m$ and $n$ iff $k$ is divisible by ${\rm lcm}(m,n)$. After that, it only remains to verify that $(g,h)^{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}=(e,e)$. (Note that ${\rm lcm}(m,n)=mn/d$.)

Comment: I might be wrong about notation, but I think $\oplus$ usually denotes coproducts, which for groups are different from sums - it is the free product. I think you want either $\times$ or $\otimes$, or even just $(G,H)$.

Comment: @AlfredYerger It denotes direct product by the convention used in my book. Odd, but....its just a symbol.

Comment: @AlfredYerger "usually"? There's no category theory here, and these are abelian groups, so $\oplus$ is common in many quarters (especially introductory texts).

Comment: @arctictern Thanks. It all fits nicely!. Finally, closure.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Certainly $\otimes$ for abelian groups could be nothing but the tensor product, and I'm pretty sure no one in their right mind would use $\oplus$ to denote the free product of groups.

Comment: @AlfredYerger, for two (a finite number of) factors there's no difference between (direct) product and coproduct.